# Chrome Dev tools - Is there a way to persist the filter in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: filter, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to preserve the filter on the Network tab in Chrome Dev tools???

E.g. if I use a filter like "-status-code:204" to exclude all responses with 204 status, it works as long as the tool window is open but would be helpful if it could be retained for new window instances.

Comment: The same goes for the filter above the console. Would be very convenient if it'd persist the input.

Comment: I've created an official feature request: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796893&can=2&q=persist&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified